# Is there a way to make permutations for file names in a for loop in linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash

The idea is that you have 3 text files lets name it **A** **B** **C** where you only have a unique column with strings (doesn't matter the content in this example). What you want is to make a join function between these three, so you'll have a join for **A - B** another one for **B - C** and a last one for **A - C** as if it is a permutation.

Let's make a graphic example.
The individual code would be

```
join -1 1 -2 1 A.txt B.txt > AB.txt
```

and so on for the other 2

Imagine **A** has

```
100
101
102
104
```

**B** has

```
101
103
104
105
```

**C** has

```
100
103
104
105
```

So **A - B** comparison (*AB.txt*) would be:

```
101
104
```

**A - C** comparison (*AC.txt*):

```
100
104
```

**B - C** comparison (*BC.txt*):

```
103
105
```

And you'll have three output file named after the comparisons **AB.txt**, **AC.txt** and **BC.txt**

Comment: Do I understand the question right: for a list of strings (filenames, in this case), how can I produce all sets of two elements each?

Comment: It's trivial to do this for three files, so do you mean for a larger number of files? What I mean is that writing this out manually would be clearer than making a loop, unless you're talking about more than three files.

Comment: @dan there are more than three files I'm just simplying the example to get the general idea only

Comment: @BenjaminW. no the question would be how can I do a join function between two files without repeating (AB only; not AB and BA)

Comment: Yes, AB and BA are the same set, since order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might look like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Read positional parameters into array
list=("$@")

# Loop over all but the last element
for ((i = 0; i < ${#list[@]} - 1; ++i)); do
    # Loop over the elements starting with the first after the one i points to
    for ((j = i + 1; j < ${#list[@]}; ++j)); do
        # Run the join command and redirect to constructed filename
        join "${list[i]}" "${list[j]}" > "${list[i]%.txt}${list[j]%.txt}".txt
    done
done
```

Notice that the `-1 1 -2 1` is the default behaviour for `join` and can be skipped.

The script has to be called with the filenames as the parameters:

```sh
./script A.txt B.txt C.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A function that does nothing but generate the possible combinations of two among its arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

combpairs() {
    local a b
    until [ $# -lt 2 ]; do
        a="$1"
        for b in "${@:2}"; do
            echo "$a - $b"
        done
        shift
    done
}
```

```
combpairs A B C D E
A - B
A - C
A - D
A - E
B - C
B - D
B - E
C - D
C - E
D - E
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the files in an array, and use the index like this:

```
files=(a.txt b.txt c.txt) # or files=(*.txt)

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do
    f1=${files[i]} f2=${files[i+1]:-$files}
    join -1 1 -2 1 "$f1" "$f2" > "${f1%.txt}${f2%.txt}.txt"
done
```

Using `echo join` to debug (and quoting `>`), this is what would be executed:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 a.txt b.txt > ab.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 b.txt c.txt > bc.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 c.txt a.txt > ca.txt
```

Or for six files:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 a.txt b.txt > ab.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 b.txt c.txt > bc.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 c.txt d.txt > cd.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 d.txt e.txt > de.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 e.txt f.txt > ef.txt
join -1 1 -2 1 f.txt a.txt > fa.txt
```

`LC_ALL=C; files(*.txt)` would use all `.txt` files in the current directory, sorted by name, which may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

One in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '{
    a[ARGIND][$0]                          # hash all files to arrays
}
END {                                      # after hashing
    for(i in a)                            # form pairs
        for(j in a)
            if(i<j) {                      # avoid self and duplicate comparisons
                f=ARGV[i] ARGV[j] ".txt"   # form output filename
                print ARGV[i],ARGV[j] > f  # output pair info
                for(k in a[i])     
                    if(k in a[j])
                        print k > f        # output matching records
            }
}' a b c
```

Output, for example:

```
$ cat ab.txt
a b
101
104
```

All files are hashed in the memory in the beginning so if the files are huge, you may run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation

```sh
declare -A seen
for a in {A,B,C}; do 
    for b in {A,B,C}; do
        [[ $a == $b || -v seen[$a$b] || -v seen[$b$a] ]] && continue
        seen[$a$b]=1
        comm -12 "$a.txt" "$b.txt" > "$a$b.txt"
    done
done
```